# Can't parse array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I damaged my brain by parse of JSON objects.
I have this js:

```
function get_cities(id) 
 {
    $('#def').hide();
    $('#cities').html('');
    $.get('/emprego/index.php/add/get_cities/'+id, null, onAjaxSuccess, "JSON" );
}
function onAjaxSuccess(data)
{
  $.each(data, function(key, val)
  {
    data.push("<option value='"+key+"'>"+val+"</option>");
  });
  $('#cities').append(data.join(''));
}
```

This code returns:

```
<select id="cities" name="cities">
[object Object],[object Object]
<option value="0">[object Object],[object Object]</option>
</select>
```

But server response is (i mean response of function with parameter):

`[[{"id":"1","name":"Lisboa"},{"id":"2","name":"Cascais"}]]`

How to parse this response to this html:

```
<select id="cities" name="cities">
<option value="1">Lisboa</option>
<option value="2">Cascais</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Server response is.... What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Your issue is the double enclosed array(s) "[[]]", seems like it should be "[]".  Remove one set of outside array brackets and all your code starts working, or use mVChr solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data` is a double enclosed array, you'll have to run your `$.each` on `data[0]`.  You'll also want to push the results to a `holder` array instead of `data` itself.  Then you'll want to pass the appropriate key of the `val` parameter:

```
function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
    var holder = [];
    $.each(data[0], function(key, val) {
        holder.push("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>");
    });
    $('#cities').append(holder.join(''));
}
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4WVU/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Holder solved problem. Code works just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

first off, you are trying to iterate over the data array, but at the same time in each iteration you are trying to push a new item onto the data (array i am guessing?).  this is a no go.

```
var newOptions = new Array();

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    newOptions.push("<option value='" + key + "'>" + val + "</option");
});
```

see what that does for you.

Answer (score 0):

If what you pasted for the server response is accurate, it means that you have two arrays.

So you should do

```
var result = [];
$.each(data[0], function(opt) { // Get the info from the array inside the array
  // opt contains {id:1, name:'Lisboa'}
  result.push('<option value="' + opt.id + '">' + opt.name + '</option>');
});
$('#cities').append(result.join(''));
```

And finally, store the process info in a different array (result).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that server response is wrong, too many '[' and ']'.

Should be like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Lisboa"},{"id":"2","name":"Cascais"}]
```

And this line:

```
data.push("<option value='"+key+"'>"+val+"</option>");
```

is also wrong, `val` there is an object. Should be:

```
data.push("<option value='"+key+"'>"+val.name+"</option>");
```